# Using stored procedure in MYSQL 5.7 to fetch and update

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have below table..

```
CREATE TABLE Coupons (
    cid INT(11) PRIMARY KEY,
    coupon_name  VARCHAR(255),
    partner     VARCHAR(255),
    is_active   INT(1)
);
INSERT INTO `table_name`(cid,coupon_name,partner_name,is_active) VALUES (0,'SWIGGYONE','SWIGGY',1);
INSERT INTO `table_name`(cid,coupon_name,partner_name,is_active) VALUES (1,'ZOMATOONE','ZOMATO',1);
INSERT INTO `table_name`(cid,coupon_name,partner_name,is_active) VALUES (2,'SWIGGYONE','SWIGGY',1);
INSERT INTO `table_name`(cid,coupon_name,partner_name,is_active) VALUES (3,'ZOMATOTWO','ZOMATO',1);
```

I wish to fetch one ACTIVE coupon from each partner and update its is_active col to 0.
I am using MYSQL 5.7

I wish to fetch those records too whose is_active is set to 0.

I dont have enough knowledge of transactions/ @variables / Stored Procedure used in MYSQL 5.7

Comment: Is upgrading to MySQL-8.0 an option?

Comment: I am sorry but no.

Comment: I am looking for a stored proc based solution. but not able to achieve it.

Comment: ' fetch one ACTIVE' - at random or is there some preferred logic?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `pr_coupons`()
LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC
CONTAINS SQL
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT ''
BEGIN
    /** Inactivate the very first coupon **/
    
    UPDATE Coupons
    SET is_active = 0
    WHERE Coupons.cid IN
    (
        SELECT cid from
        (
            SELECT cid
            FROM Coupons
            WHERE Coupons.is_active = 1
            GROUP BY Coupons.partner
        ) AS inner_table
    );
    
    /** Select active coupons **/
    
    SELECT *
    FROM Coupons
    WHERE is_active = 1;
END
```